# Chrome multiple-people/profile-switcher feature - how to set active person so that new opened web will go that person 's window

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

I use [profile switcher feature in Chrome browser](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and want to have new web opened from my OS to be in a selected person aka. set active person so that new opened web will go to that person 's window.

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=Chrome%20multiple-people%2Fprofile-switcher%20feature%20-%20how%20to%20set%20active%20person%20so%20that%20new%20opened%20web%20will%20go%20that%20person%20%27s%20window&oq=Chrome%20multiple-people%2Fprofile-switcher%20feature%20-%20how%20to%20set%20active%20person%20so%20that%20new%20opened%20web%20will%20go%20that%20person%20%27s%20window&aqs=chrome..69i57.334j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [search on our site](https://superuser.com/search?q=Chrome%20multiple-people%2Fprofile-switcher%20feature%20-%20how%20to%20set%20active%20person%20so%20that%20new%20opened%20web%20will%20go%20that%20person%20%27s%20window) result little helpful so I ask here.

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/109589/make-google-chrome-with-specific-user-profile-as-default-browser  ,    https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/i0vo6KbMc80   ,    https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/jbLSCIw-XyY

Comment: May you brief the main solution as an answer to get it accepted please?