# Start chrome with a specific default profile?

Tags: google-chrome

Now I know this has been asked before but it seems that all answers I have found didn't work,
Specifically nothing in this article worked, I tested all 19 answers ([Make Google chrome with specific user profile as default browser](https://superuser.com/questions/109589/make-google-chrome-with-specific-user-profile-as-default-browser)). Now it could be because that article is outdated so I am asking for the updated method.
My question is if I open a chrome.exe shortcut with no additional attributes, how can I do it so it opens a specific default profile every time and not the last profile that was in use?
I am using windows 10 21H1 for clearance and chrome 89 (The latest version)

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Default"` worked for me.  It also worked with Microsoft Edge (with the proper directory obviously).  I changed `Profile 1` since the directory name is "Default" not "Profile 1"

Comment: I cant add --profile-directory="Default" to Chrome.exe. and I am not using a shortcut to do so. could you tell me how you added that line?

Comment: You can either use a shortcut or within a command prompt run the command. How are you launching Chrome if you are not using a shortcut?

Comment: Say I do a windows search or use an app like Wox that performs a web search with chrome but isn't using a shortcut to open it.

Comment: What you want is not possible unless you use a different shortcut to launch Chrome with each profile.  Chrome doesn't have a profile switcher like Firefox. Even then Firefox wouldn't allow you to do what you describe either.